# How to getPath of Gedmo Tree element using symfony3, doctrine2 and stofDoctrineExtensionsBundle

Tags: doctrine-orm, tree, symfony, doctrine-extensions, stofdoctrineextensions

I am using Symfony v3.0.4, Doctrine v2.5.4 and StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle [1] in order to manage Tree structure.

To setup Tree structure I used documentation on Symfony.com [2] followed by documentatnion on GitHub [3].

Then I proceeded with tree setup - used tree entity from example [4] and used code in [5] to create a tree.

<strike>I did not use [6] and [7] as it seems not necessary (as far as I can tell tree works and displays without it).</strike> See update.

So far I have a tree structure in database and to display it I modified example [8]. Like this:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use AppBundle\Entity\Category;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

class TreeController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/tree", name="tree")
     */
    public function treeAction(Request $request)
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $repo = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Category');
        $options = array(
            'decorate' => true,
            'rootOpen' => '<ul>',
            'rootClose' => '</ul>',
            'childOpen' => '<li>',
            'childClose' => '</li>',
            'nodeDecorator' => function($node) {
                return '<a href="/some_path/...">'. $node['title'] .'</a>';
            }
        );

        $htmlTree = $repo->childrenHierarchy(
            null, /* starting from root nodes */
            false, /* false: load all children, true: only direct */
            $options
        );

        return $this->render('tree/tree_show.html.twig', array('project_tree' => $htmlTree));
    }
}
```

if I modify one line like this:

```
'nodeDecorator' => function($node) {
    return '<a href="/project_path/'. implode('/', getPath($node)) .'">'. $node['title'] .'</a>';
}
```

in order to get path to each element of the tree i get error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function AppBundle\Controller\getPath()
500 Internal Server Error - FatalThrowableError
```

- [1] [stofDoctrineExtensionsBundle on GitHub](https://github.com/stof/StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle);
- [2] [stofDoctrineExtensinsBundnle documentation on Symfony.com](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle/index.html);
- [3] [Gedmo Tree documentation on GitHub](https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/doc/tree.md);
- [4] [Gedmo Tree > Tree Entity example](https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/doc/tree.md#tree-entity-example);
- [5] [Gedmo Tree > Basic Usage Example](https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/doc/tree.md#basic-usage-examples);
- [6] [DID NOT USE: Gedmo Tree > Tree Repositories](https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/doc/tree.md#tree-repositories);
- [7] [Gedmo Tree > Use Abstract Repositories](https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/doc/tree.md#extend-abstract-repositores);
- [8] [Tree html output example](https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/doc/tree.md#customize-html-tree-output);
- [9] [NestedTreeRepository has method getPath()](http://apigen.juzna.cz/doc/l3pp4rd/DoctrineExtensions/class-Gedmo.Tree.Entity.Repository.NestedTreeRepository.html#_getPath).

As seen in [9] NestedTreeRepositry has a method getPath().

Update: I tried [6] but did not manage to set it up. Then I tried [7] set it up ok, but still error remains the same!

Please advise. 
Thank you for your time and knowledge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use functon `getPath()` that exists in

`"vendor/gedmo/doctrine-extensions/lib/Gedmo/Tree/Entity/Repository" in the file "NestedTreeRepository.php"`

or in

`"vendor/gedmo/doctrine-extensions/lib/Gedmo/Tree/Traits/Repository/ORM" in the file "NestedTreeRepositoryTrait.php"`

one has to modify code block like this:

```
nodeDecorator' => function($node) use ($repo)
{
    return '<a href="/project_path/'. @implode('/', $repo->getPath($repo->findOneBy(array('id' => $node['id'])))) .'">'. $node['title'] .'</a>';
}
```

note added

`use ($repo)`

and

`@implode('/', $repo->getPath($repo->findOneBy(array('id' => $node['id']))))`

with this - there should be no `undefined function` error

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, hence I used `getPathInfo()` instead, and it worked fine.